# How to add SWRL vocabularies into Jena Framework

Tags: sparql, jena, ontology, swrl, urn

Hi I am an Ontology beginner,

I have built an Ontology and saved the RDF file with rule enabled using Protege. I am going to build a web service that takes some inputs from the Ontology. The inputs can be provided by querying the arguments, class and property predicates under swrl:something swrlb:something tags.

I am using java language and trying Jena framework. But there is no SWRL-related vocabulary, even though I have imported rule reasoners [I am not sure whether importing reasoners will add the SWRL vocabularies].

Are there any hints to add SWRL vocabularies into Jena framework?

I haven't looked into Jena rules yet, I believe that it is different to SWRL.

Thanks,

Comment: There is no SWRL reasoner in Jena so I'm wondering what you want to achieve by "adding SWRL vocabulary"?

Comment: Hi @AKSW

model.listResourcesWithProperty(**RDFS.subClassOf**);

How to retrieve any SWRL.argument1 tags to replace the bold syntax?

Comment: For the pellet reasoner, SWRL VOCABULARY for jena is here :  https://github.com/Galigator/openllet/tree/integration/module-jena/src/main/java/openllet/jena/vocabulary  (as well as the OWL2 vocabulary); maybe you should watch "owlapi5" instead of "jena"

Comment: Thanks @Galigator!

Comment: Well, now I understand what you mean. But this are just constants in Java which are shortcuts for the URIs of the elements. I don't understand why you need them. Jena only contains the most common ones for convenience, e.g. OWL, RDF and RDFS. If you have a look at the source code of those classes, you can see that all you have to do is to call `model.createResource(uri)` or `model.createProperty(uri)` for any element of any vocabulary that you need. E.g. `model.listResourcesWithProperty(model.createProperty(http://www.w3.org/2003/11/swrlb#lessThan))`

Comment: Thanks @AKSW for the explanation. I am trying to build a prediction model by taking some inputs from an RDF..